# Concatenate column B row values in single cell against column A

Tags: excel, vba

I have data around 400+ records in column "A" & various detail in column "B". A total of 3000+ rows in the sheet which look like
Example:

```
Column A    Column B

CHI150  UPS1

CHI150  TOWER1

CHI150  TOWER2

CHI160  EB1

CHI160  UPS1

CHI160  TOWER1

CHI163  EB1

CHI163  TOWER2

CHI163  UPS2

CHI195  TOWER1

CHI195  EB1
```

I want do concatenate the data like below mentioned.

```
Column A    Column B

CHI150  UPS1, TOWER1, TOWER2

CHI160  EB1, UPS1, TOWER1

CHI163  EB1, TOWER2, UPS2

CHI195  TOWER1, EB1
```

Kindly give the solution & Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the data in Column A & B from A2 and B2 cells respectively..

```css
Sub test()
'change the sheet name as yours
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
'Change the range as yours and you need update the column as well in cells(rows.count,1)
Set Rng = Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
Set rng1 = Range("D2", Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp))

Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Copy
'copy pasteing the column A and removing duplicates
Range("D2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

ActiveCell.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

' now concordinating the values
For Each cell In rng1
    For Each cell1 In Rng

        If cell.Value = cell1.Value Then
            If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell1.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Else
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value & ", " & cell1.Offset(0, 1).Value
            End If
        End If
        
    Next cell1
Next cell

End Sub
```

[image]

The above macro will generated the result in column D form D2. Hope this is what your expecting..

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for making the changes in your question to explain it better.

I took a sample sheet similar to your problem, and was able to get the desired result in a new column C. Try below steps

1. Copy the value of B1 to C1
2. Put below formula to all rows of column C starting from row 2 (i.e. C2). This will check if value on column A at current row is similar to the previous row, and shall append the values of the column B to the calculated value in Column C for previous row.

   =IF(A2=A1, (C1 & ", " & B2), B2)
3. For all the rows of column D, put below formula starting with row 1

   =IF(A1=A2,"","Changed")
4. This should fill some of the rows for column D with "Changed", you could then filter for the column D for only the records that contain "Changed" as value.

This should get you desired result.

Comment: Hi Thanks, i know the CONCATENATE function. Please read my post again. & i gave example for both the data & result.

Comment: Thanks for modifying the question, it is clear now. I've changed my solution which should hopefully give you the required solution.

Comment: Dear @Elavazhuthi were you able to find a solution?